# What is "lifting" in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, functional-programming, lifting

Sometimes when I read articles in the Scala ecosystem I read the term "lifting" / "lifted". Unfortunately, it is not explained what that exactly means. I did some research, and it seems that lifting has something to do with functional values or something like that, but I was not able to find a text that explains what lifting actually is about in a beginner friendly way.

There is additional confusion through the [Lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_%28web_framework%29) framework which has lifting in its name, but it doesn't help answer the question.

**What is "lifting" in Scala?**

Answer (score 321, accepted):

There are a few usages:

### PartialFunction

Remember a `PartialFunction[A, B]` is a function defined for some subset of the domain `A` (as specified by the `isDefinedAt` method). You can "lift" a `PartialFunction[A, B]` into a `Function[A, Option[B]]`. That is, a function defined over the *whole* of `A` but whose values are of type `Option[B]`

This is done by the explicit invocation of the method `lift` on `PartialFunction`.

```
scala> val pf: PartialFunction[Int, Boolean] = { case i if i > 0 => i % 2 == 0}
pf: PartialFunction[Int,Boolean] = <function1>

scala> pf.lift
res1: Int => Option[Boolean] = <function1>

scala> res1(-1)
res2: Option[Boolean] = None

scala> res1(1)
res3: Option[Boolean] = Some(false)
```

### Methods

You can "lift" a method invocation into a function. This is called *eta-expansion* (thanks to [@Ben James](/users/189179) for this). So for example:

```
scala> def times2(i: Int) = i * 2
times2: (i: Int)Int
```

We lift a method into a function by applying the *underscore*

```
scala> val f = times2 _
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f(4)
res0: Int = 8
```

Note the fundamental difference between methods and functions. `res0` is an **instance** (i.e. it is a *value*) of the (function) type `(Int => Int)`

### Functors

A *functor* (as defined by **scalaz**) is some "container" (I use the term *extremely* loosely), `F` such that, if we have an `F[A]` and a function `A => B`, then we can get our hands on an `F[B]` (think, for example, `F = List` and the `map` method)

We can encode this property as follows:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] { 
  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B]
}
```

This is isomorphic to being able to "lift" the function `A => B` into the domain of the functor. That is:

```
def lift[F[_]: Functor, A, B](f: A => B): F[A] => F[B]
```

That is, if `F` is a functor, and we have a function `A => B`, we have a function `F[A] => F[B]`. You might try and implement the `lift` method - it's pretty trivial.

### Monad Transformers

As *hcoopz* says below (and I've just realized that this would have saved me from writing a ton of unnecessary code), the term "lift" also has a meaning within **Monad Transformers**. Recall that a monad transformers are a way of "stacking" monads on top of each other (monads do not compose).

So for example, suppose you have a function which returns an `IO[Stream[A]]`. This can be converted to the monad transformer `StreamT[IO, A]`. Now you may wish to "lift" some other value an `IO[B]` perhaps to that it is also a `StreamT`. You could either write this:

```
StreamT.fromStream(iob map (b => Stream(b)))
```

Or this:

```
iob.liftM[StreamT]
```

this begs the question: *why do I want to convert an `IO[B]` into a `StreamT[IO, B]`?*. The answer would be "to take advantage of composition possibilities". Let's say you have a function `f: (A, B) => C`

```
lazy val f: (A, B) => C = ???
val cs = 
  for {
    a <- as                //as is a StreamT[IO, A]
    b <- bs.liftM[StreamT] //bs was just an IO[B]
  }
  yield f(a, b)

cs.toStream //is a Stream[IO[C]], cs was a StreamT[IO, C]
```

Comment: Delving further into **scalaz**, _lifting_ also comes up in relation to _monad transformers_. If I have a `MonadTrans` instance `T` for `M` and a `Monad` instance for `N`, then `T.liftM` can be used to _lift_ a value of type `N[A]` to a value of type `M[N, A]`.

Comment: Perfect! Just one more reason to say: Scala - the best. Which could be lifted to Martin Odersky & Co - the best. I even would to use `liftM` for that, but didn't manage understand how to do that properly. Guys, you're rock!

Comment: In **Methods** section _...res0 is an instance (i.e. it is a value) of the (function) type (Int => Int)..._ Shouldn't `f` be an instance, not `res0`?

Answer (score 27):

Note any collection that extends `PartialFunction[Int, A]` (as pointed out by oxbow_lakes) may be lifted; thus for instance

```
Seq(1,2,3).lift
Int => Option[Int] = <function1>
```

which turns a partial function into a total function where values not defined in the collection are mapped onto `None`,

```
Seq(1,2,3).lift(2)
Option[Int] = Some(3)

Seq(1,2,3).lift(22)
Option[Int] = None
```

Moreover,

```
Seq(1,2,3).lift(2).getOrElse(-1)
Int = 3

Seq(1,2,3).lift(22).getOrElse(-1)
Int = -1
```

This shows a neat approach to avoid *index out of bounds* exceptions.

Answer (score 21):

Another usage of *lifting* that I've come across in papers (not necessarily Scala-related ones) is overloading a function from `f: A -> B` with `f: List[A] -> List[B]` (or sets, multisets, ...). This is often used to simplify formalisations because it then doesn't matter whether `f` is applied to an individual element or to multiple elements.

This kind of overloading is often done declaratively, e.g.,

```
f: List[A] -> List[B]
f(xs) = f(xs(1)), f(xs(2)), ..., f(xs(n))
```

or

```
f: Set[A] -> Set[B]
f(xs) = \bigcup_{i = 1}^n f(xs(i))
```

or imperatively, e.g.,

```
f: List[A] -> List[B]
f(xs) = xs map f
```

Comment: This is the "lifting into a functor" which oxbow_lakes describes.

Comment: @BenJames True indeed. To my defence: oxbow_lakes' answer wasn't there yet when I started to write mine.

Answer (score 6):

There is also *unlifting*, which is the inverse process to lifting.

If lifting is defined as

> turning a partial function `PartialFunction[A, B]` into a total
>   function `A => Option[B]`

then unlifting is

> turning a total function `A => Option[B]` into a partial function
>   `PartialFunction[A, B]`

Scala standard library defines [`Function.unlift`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Function$.html#unlift[T,R](f:T=>Option[R]):PartialFunction[T,R]) as

> ```
> def unlift[T, R](f: (T) ⇒ Option[R]): PartialFunction[T, R]
> ```

For example, play-json library provides [unlift](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-functional/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/functional/syntax/package.scala#L34) to help with construction of [JSON serialisers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes):

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Location(lat: Double, long: Double)

implicit val locationWrites: Writes[Location] = (
  (JsPath \ "lat").write[Double] and
  (JsPath \ "long").write[Double]
)(unlift(Location.unapply))
```