# Using userId with Gatling DSL

Tags: gatling

I am using session.userId to parametrize my test requests like this:

```
exec(http("get request")
  .get((s:Session) => "somebaseUrl/" + s.userId.toString ))
```

Is it possible to get sesion userId differently, so my request addresses are more DRY, eg I won't have to use lambda?

I tried using gatling DSL:

```
exec(http("get request")
  .get("somebaseUrl/${userId}")
```

but then I get: `No attribute named 'userId' is defined` error

I could just calculate some random id to my tests, but why when gatling already does this.

Only solution that I came up with is saving userId to some different attribute like this:

```
exec((s:Session) => s.set("user_id",s.userId)),
exec(http("test").get("${user_id}"))
```

but that doesn't seem right, and you have to make sure to call the set before all other requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The userId is some internal details. Gatling Expression language only exposes Session attributes, ie the attributes Map content.

Either use the first way you described, with a function, or don't use Gatling internals and set your own UUID attribute (feeder, exec(function), etc).

Comment: bare with me, as I'm scala/gatling noob :). 
I probably could save lambdas to variable, and call them right? 
what should I pass to that variable as a parameter though?

Same applies to function, I can extract lamdas to function, I have no idea what to pass to them. I mean how to get a session instance.

In docs, there is `val session: Session = ???` which doesn't help either :) 
http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/session/session_api.html#id2

Comment: If you don't know how to write a function in Scala, get a look at a Scala tutorial then: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/quickstart.html#a-word-on-scala

Comment: I know how to write a scala function, I don't know, how to pass an argument with session in gatling. I mean, what is actually passing current session to a lambda in for example .get((s:Session) => "something" +s.userId)). And how to pass the session as argument to normal function.

Comment: This makes me think you don't understand what a function is: some piece of code that you can pass as a parameter so that it's invoked elsewhere. What   actually invokes those functions in Gatling is an implementation detail and not a user concern.

Comment: It is possible, and also probable, that I'm thinking wrong about this. Or cannot express it correctly. 
But I want a simple thing, have a function that does exactly what this lamda does `(s:Session) => s.userId.toString` - in my mind that means - take given session s, and return its userId string. I know how to write a function that does this `def returnUID(s:Session): String = s.userId.toString`, I just have no idea, how to pass a session to it. As I have no idea, how the lamda is called.

Comment: No offense, but you indeed look like you're missing some fundamental concepts understanding.
I suspect you're trying to skip the initial learning phase and think like you're used to in procedural language.
Take a few hours to go through a Scala tutorial, such as Twitter's Scala School.

`def` is not a function, it's a method.
But it can be automatically lifted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965059/what-is-lifting-in-scala.

Comment: Twitter's Scala School - basics: `Functions
You can create functions with def.` .. Yeah I'll probably need to go deeper. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using gatling internals you could use a feeder:

```
var userId = 0
feed(Iterator.continually(Map("userId" -> {
      userId += 1
      userId}.toString)))
```