# Does "Lifting" in functional programming follows strict rules?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, lifting

I have looked into "lifting" q/a's, examples it seemed to me lift function is just like any transformation function that changes the shape (like monad transformation).

Am I missing any point or lift function("lifting concept") does have any rules ?

If not is it just concept in functional transformations?

Comment: Can you make one or more specific examples of lifting something somewhere? What kind of transformation are you talking about? I'm having trouble following.

Comment: e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965059/what-is-lifting-in-scala val pf: PartialFunction[Int, Boolean] = { case i if i > 0 => i % 2 == 0} then calling pf.lift

Comment: or in examples like here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers#Lifting

Comment: The rules for "lifting" depend on what "lifting" means. If lifting means `liftM` then the rules are the `Functor` laws because `liftM` is another name for `fmap`.

Comment: I think you're trying to generalize something that isn't generalizable. The Scala example lifts a function into a larger domain. The Haskell example is a monad transformer lift. There's also `liftM` which lifts a function into a functor scope. Each of these on their own follows rules, but the naming is just a coincidence. Like how object-oriented programmers and functional programmers mean totally different things when they talk about "composition".

Comment: Sadly `lift` is one of those words which means whatever the speaker wants it to mean (`hoist`'s another one), though it usually has some connotation of using something in a larger context.

Comment: "lifting" typically refers to an [injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). The simplest examples (I can think of) of injections are `Left :: a -> Either a b`, `Right :: b -> Either a b`, and `Identity :: a -> Identity` (a trivial one). `lift` (from `MonadTrans`), `liftM`, and the scala examples in the linked question are all injections. (Aside: all the claims here that "lift means whatever you want it to mean" are silly. Clearly a word means whatever you chose! But clearly there is a commonly understood underlying concept)

Comment: @user2407038, usually, but not always. `data U2 m a = U2` `instance MonadTrans U2 where lift _ = U2` defines a perfectly valid `MonadTrans` instance, but not an injection. The same goes for `liftM`/`fmap` to a trivial functor. Injectivity is also certainly insufficient for most senses of "lift". So I don't think injectivity really has anything to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

Lifting doesn't change the 'shape', just the 'type'.  By this I mean that lifting a function into, e.g., a `List<A>` results in a `List<B>`.  The shape (`List`) doesn't change, but the specific type may.

You are right that it is similar to any other transformation.  In fact, the standard operation `map` is the mechanism of 'lifting' a function of a single variable into the Functor (the datatype being mapped over).  So, you can think of `map` as `lift1`, then you have `lift2` (for functions of two variables), etc.